# Can I Restore My Website Pages Without mySQL Database?

Tags: backup

I accidentally deleted mySQL database, and I have no way to restore the database.

I still have all the files like wp-admin, wp-content, wp-config.php and so on.

If I create a new website with all blank pages.  Would there be an easy way to restore my previous pages from the files I have?

Comment: Did you used any backup plugin in your site ??

Answer (score 3):

Content in WordPress is inside the WordPress database.

If you have deleted the WP database, then the content is gone. Installing a new WP instance will create a new, mostly blank database.

So, unless you have a backup copy of your database to restore, your content is gone.

Your hosting place may have made a backup of things, including your database. So you might contact them to see if they can restore your databases.

Unless the hosting place has a backup copy (many do), you might be out of luck. Sorry.

(For 'lurkers' ... do you have a backed up / offsite copy of your WordPress database? There are many plugins that will do that for you.)

Answer (score 2):

You seem out of luck, my friend, but search your page here: https://web.archive.org/ it MAY save your sanity.